# I can't run dart/flutter code due to this error. Any help? I

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart, visual-studio-code

Kotlin could not find the required JDK tools in the Java installation 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_291' used by Gradle. Make sure Gradle is running on a JDK, not JRE.

I am using Visual Studio Code.

Comment: the error already tell you, you need install Java JDK not Java JRE. See https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase8u211-later-archive-downloads.html : jdk-8u311-windows-i586.exe or jdk-8u311-windows-x64.exe

Comment: If you've already installed a jdk, update your path.

Answer (score 0):

you can check it is already installed or not with executing

**which java**

command on terminal, then you can change your path on system environments.

Answer (score 0):

**flutter doctor** command gives you every dependency problem you might be missing